# Continuous location update in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, .net-maui

I've built a simple MAUI test app that reads the location every 3 seconds and writes it to a label control. When testing in Android (both on emulator and device) I can see the Android location icon appearing and disappearing each time a location is being read.

When using other tracking apps for reference, the location icon is always on, so I guess there is some way to keep the connection to the GPS open while the app is running.
Is this possible in MAUI?

```
CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;
CancellationToken token;

private async void OnStartClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tokenSource = new();
    token = tokenSource.Token;
    
    PermissionStatus permissionStatus = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationAlways>();

    if (permissionStatus == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        Task locationTask = Task.Run(() => UpdateLocation(token), token);
    }
}

private async Task UpdateLocation(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            viewModel.DebugText = $"distance cancel requested";
            return;
        }

        GeolocationRequest request = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Best, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        CancellationTokenSource _cancelTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Location location = await Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync(request, _cancelTokenSource.Token);

        while (location == null)
            Thread.Sleep(100);

        viewModel.LastLocation = location;

        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: the MAUI Geolocator offers a limited set of functionality compared to what is actually available on the underlying platforms.  You can continuously monitor location (this drains battery) and get event driven updates when it changes.  The old Xamarin [geolocator plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) allowed this.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that Xamarin plugin. Let's hope the MAUI team will include this functionality in .NET 7.

Comment: you can do this yourself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code

Comment: Interesting! I will try it out and update. Thanks.

Comment: I found full implementation (and tested it successfully) for Android and iPhone (MAUI) on Bohdan's blog here https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/maui-native-mobile-location-updates-444939dff3af

Answer (score 1):

There is a Geolocation Plugin for Maui to do continuous GPS logging.

https://github.com/gktval/Maui-GeolocatorPlugin

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Geolocator.Plugin/

This was ported from Xamarin's GeolocationPlugin.

Below is an example of how to use it in code. Then create methods to handle `CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionChanged` and  `CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionError`.

```
public async void ToggleGPS(bool toggleOn)
{
   if (toggleOn)
   {
       if (await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 5, true, new ListenerSettings
       {
           ActivityType = ActivityType.AutomotiveNavigation,
           AllowBackgroundUpdates = true,
           DeferLocationUpdates = false,
           ListenForSignificantChanges = false,
           PauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false,
        }))
        {
           CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionChanged;
           CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError += CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionError;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (await CrossGeolocator.Current.StopListeningAsync())
        {
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged -= CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionChanged;
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError -= CrossGeolocator_Current_PositionError;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried using this in .NET Maui app, however like the original plugin it derived from it throws: "System.NotImplementedException: 'This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation.'" This occurs as soon as it is accessed: var test = CrossGeolocator.Current;

Comment: It may have only been working for Android. A new nuget to version 1.0.2 should have fixed a null reference to Windows/IOS/Mac.

Comment: Also good to know that the listening feature will be added in MAUI Essentials for the .NET 8 release, it's already in preview (https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/9572)

Comment: @tval I have tried your plugin in MAUI .NET 7 and it works, I can subscribe to the notifications. But when the application is not in the foreground, the notifications stops. I use the plugin inside a ForegroundService, but anyway, when the application is not in the foreground, the notifications stops. I have seen in your code that you use AllowBackgroundUpdates = true, but it seems it doesn't work in my case, in the background I don't get notifications.